# Valgrind Suppressed Errors... Grrr

Tags: c, valgrind

I recognize that many do not consider "still reachable" memory leaks to be true memory leaks. However, I'm trying to get Valgrind to report errors whenever an error is "still reachable". To be more specific, this is my current output:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
  in use at exit: 23,221,680 bytes in 25 blocks
  total heap usage: 27 allocs, 2 frees, 23,222,816 bytes allocated

  Searching for pointers to 25 not-freed blocks
  Checked 49,347,544 bytes

  672 bytes in 24 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
       at 0x4C29792: malloc (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x2011F54: (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x405C75: main (** DETAILS OMITTED **)

  23,221,008 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
       at 0x4C29792: malloc (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x2011F54: (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x21B34CC: (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x20125DF: (** DETAILS OMITTED **)
       by 0x406D14: main (** DETAILS OMITTED **)

LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    still reachable: 23,221,680 bytes in 25 blocks
    suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

The two suppressed errors are coming from "still reachable" errors. I would like these to be considered proper errors so that the program returns an error code.

Comment: How do you run `valgrind`? With what options? Have you tried adding the `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` options?

Comment: Why are you confident that the "still reachable" bytes are associated with the suppressed errors?  Such an association would not be *my* first-glance expectation.

Comment: My apologies for excluding that detail: valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --error-exitcode=1 --track-origins=yes --log-file=LOG_FILE_NAME -v EXECUTABLE_NAME

Comment: There are 2 "still reachable" errors. The sum of their lost bytes is roughly equal to the number of "still reachable" bytes at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow.  You haven't presented any information about the suppressed errors or the amount of memory attributed to them.

Comment: ```672 bytes in 24 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2``` and ```23,221,008 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2```

Comment: They're essentially ```malloc``` calls in the main function that are never freed. The issue isn't so much resolving them. The issue is getting Valgrind to recognize that these are errors.

Comment: You are missing the point, @RomanParise.  If you want Valgrind to exit with an error status when not all memory is freed then that's one thing, but you have also asserted that the "still unreachable" loss records are associated with the suppressed errors, which is almost certainly false.  That there are two of each is a coincidence.

Comment: I edited the post. As far as I can tell, it's pretty clear that there are only two suppressed errors and that they are coming from these still-reachable leaks. Maybe I'm missing something though...

Comment: The reporting depends on the operating system, and whether there are valid *exclusion* files that mask system allocated memory properly. C being simpler for `valgrind` to handle is likely to have valid exclusion files that mask everything but user-allocations (however recent versions fail to mask the system allocated I/O memory). C++ being more system reliant on allocations behind the scene is less likely to provide full masking for all but user-allocated memory. So what is being reported as "In Use" may be allocations you have no control over. But `27 allocs, 2 frees` doesn't look that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The two suppressed errors are coming from "still reachable" errors.

Almost surely not.  The results of the leak check performed at program exit are largely separate from the analysis of erroneous memory accesses performed as the program runs.  You can test with a dummy program such as this one that still-reachable memory does not produce a suppressed error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    void *p = malloc(8);

    return (int) p;
}
```

I get

> ```
> ==22685== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==22685==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==22685==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==22685==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==22685==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==22685==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==22685== 
> ==22685== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==22685== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

Note well that 8 bytes are reported still reachable, and there are ***zero*** suppressed (or unsuppressed) errors.

> I would like these to be considered proper errors so that the program returns an error code.

The point of suppressions is to ignore known, believed-harmless erroneous behavior, typically of system libraries.  Although you can write your own suppression files, the suppressions you get by default arise from components out of your control.

It's an altogether different thing to exit with an error code in the event of various kinds of leak.  You wrote in comments that you are running your valgrind test like so:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --error-exitcode=1 \
    --track-origins=yes --log-file=LOG_FILE_NAME -v EXECUTABLE_NAME
```

Notably missing from the options you are providing is `--errors-for-leak-kinds`, which is separate from `--show-leak-kinds`, and defaults to `definite,possible`.  The combination `--error-exitcode=1 --errors-for-leak-kinds=all` should cause valgrind to count (and report) all classes of leaks as errors, and therefore to exit with status 1 in the event that it detects any memory still allocated when the program exits.

Comment: The ```--errors-for-leak-kinds=all``` fixed my problem. Thank you!